# Get IntelliJ to respect multiple @throws annotations in Scala dependency from a Java project

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, exception, annotations

I have a Java project which depends on a Scala project. Inside that Scala project, there is a particular method that uses two `@throws(classOf[<some exception>])`:

```
  @throws(classOf[ExtensionException])
  @throws(classOf[LogoException])
  def perform(args: Array[Argument], context: Context)
```

However, intellij doesn't seem to know about both when I override the method:

[image]

The error is that the base method does not throw `ExtensionException`. The code compiles fine. Note that `LogoException` appears to be okay when I delete `ExtensionException` from  throws declaration.

So, is there a way I can get Intellij to respect both throws declarations? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in IntelliJ. I've run into it myself, and reported it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7454